# How to pass object of type Parcelable to a Fragment using Navigation type safeargs plugin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am rewriting my simple UI app to use Navigation architecture component, I need to pass a Pojo that implements Parcelable,  have not seen any doc on how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to make this work @Po10cio?

Comment: Nop, but at the moment, Navigation Architecture component has added parcelable args.

Answer (score 50):

Since `safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha03` you can use `Parcelable` objects by using their fully qualified class name:

```
<argument
    android:name="item"
    app:argType="com.example.app.model.Item"/>
```

> Parcelable arguments are now supported, using a fully qualified class name for app:type. The only default value supported is "@null" (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79563966)

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

---

To support nullability one has to use `android:defaultValue="@null"` with `app:nullable="true"`.

Comment: How to use this with Proguard? I get a crash:

`     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.models.User`

Comment: @PatrickSteiger You need to keep such classes using ```-keep class className``` rule.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working with nested classes. `com.example.app.TestFragment.ViewModel` won't work for example. Did anyone find a workaround for this?

Comment: Probably `TestFragment$ViewModel`

Comment: I love you @EpicPandaForce, works!

 I'll add some keywords here so people can find it sooner:
argtype parcelable classnotfoundexception dex

Comment: Please note: The key is to use the entire path com.example.app.model.Item as opposed to just Item.

Answer (score 23):

I know the answer is already there but this may help someone. `Code snippet`

In build.gradle add this dependancy

```sh
ext{
     ...
     navigation_version = '1.0.0-alpha11'
}
dependencies {
     ...
     classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
}
```

In app/build.gradle

```sh
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
...
```

In Navigation graph

```sh
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/source_fragment_id"
            android:name="app.test.SourceFragment"
            android:label="@string/source_fragment_label"
            tools:layout="@layout/source_fragment_layout">

         <action
                android:id="@+id/action_source_fragment_to_destination_fragment"
                app:destination="@id/destination_fragment_id"
                ...
                />


</fragment>

<fragment
            android:id="@+id/destination_fragment_id"
            android:name="app.test.DestinationFragment"
            android:label="@string/destination_fragment_label"
            tools:layout="@layout/destination_fragment_layout">

        <argument
                android:name="variableName"
                app:argType="app.test.data.model.CustomModel" />

        ...

</fragment>
```

> Note: CustomModel should be Parcelable or Serializable.

When navigating to this DestinationFragment from SourceFragment

```sh
val direction = SourceFragmentDirections.ActionSourceFragmentToDestinationFragment(customModel)
findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

Now retrieving the value from bundle in DestinationFragment

```sh
...
import app.test.DestinationFragmentArgs.fromBundle

class DestinationFragment : Fragment() {
   val variableName by lazy {
       fromBundle(arguments!!).variableName
   }

   ...
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        Log.e(DESTINATION_FRAGMENT_TAG,"onCreateView")

        //Can use CustomModel variable here i.e. variableName


   }

}
```

Comment: What should I set for "android:defaultValue" in nav graph? it crashes without default value. I found the answer, you have to add "android:defaultValue="@null" too.

Comment: @ParisaBaastani It's not a mandatory field, ideally it should not crash. Which nav component version you are using?

Comment: I was using 2.3.2 version and I remembered that it throws exception without default value.

Answer (score 10):

Right now you can't use safe args with types apart from *integer*, *string*, *inferred* and *reference*, there's an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79563966) opened asking for other types.

What you can do now is to normally pass a *bundle* when using the *navigate()* method to navigate to a destination:

```
var bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

And you can use the usual `getArguments` (or just arguments in kotlin) to retrieve that:

```
val tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount)
tv.text = arguments.getString("amount")
```

Comment: Where is `bundleOf` from?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It used to be internal to the jetbrains plugin but that was deprecated in favor of the ktx one

Comment: Looks like the issue mentioned above was fixed as of July 10, 2018. "Parcelable support has been added and will also be available in alpha03."

Answer (score 6):

You can use `boolean`, `reference`, `integer`, `long`, `string`, `enum`, `parcelable` and even `serializable`. But forget about the last one ;-)

Better use the latest plugin version `safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha08` and specify the fully qualified classname:

```
<fragment
    ...>
    <argument
        android:name="data"
        app:argType="com.example.ParcelableData" />
</fragment>
```

from your

```
package com.example

data class ParcelableData(val content: String) : Parcelable { ... }
```

And you can send arrays of all the `argType`s:

```
<argument
        android:name="data"
        app:argType="string[]" />
```